# Excel macro code to change the axis title and its font size, font type

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

TRY TO USE Excel macro code to change the axis title and its font size, font type

get wrong message: "object does not support this property or method" need expert give me suggestions or solution, thanks !

```
.Axes(xlCategory).HasTitle = True

 With .Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle

.Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Text = "Position(nm)"  'X-axis title

.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Size = 10 'X-axis coordinate number size

.Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Font.Size = 14  'X-axis title word font size

.Axes(xlCategory).TickMarkSpacing = 3

.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelSpacing = 5
```

Comment: `AxisTitle` doesn't have an `Axes` property.  Try commenting out that `With`

Answer (score 0):

You want something more like this:

```
With .Axes(xlCategory)
    .HasTitle = True
    .AxisTitle.Text = "Position(nm)"  'X-axis title
    .TickLabels.Font.Size = 10 'X-axis coordinate number size
    .AxisTitle.Font.Size = 14  'X-axis title word font size
    .TickMarkSpacing = 3
    .TickLabelSpacing = 5
    '....
    '....
```